# How to get the user to enter a float in entry box?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

If I create an entry box like so:

```
myentry = Entry ()
myentry.place (x = 54,y = 104)
```

the value that the user enters is a string value.  What do I have to add so that the entry is a float?  I have tried to write "float" in the parentheses beside Entry but it didn't work and showed me an error saying that tk() does not support float.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Use `v = StringVar()`, then use `Entry(parent, textvariable=v)`. Then you can get the variable as float using `float(v.get())`.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple script to demonstrate how to do what you want:

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Button, Entry, END

root = Tk()

def click():
    """Handle button click"""

    # Get the input
    val = myentry.get()

    try:
        # Try to make it a float
        val = float(val)
        print val
    except ValueError:
        # Print this if the input cannot be made a float
        print "Bad input"

    # Clear the entrybox
    myentry.delete(0, END)

# Made this to demonstrate
Button(text="Print input", command=click).grid()

myentry = Entry()
myentry.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

When you click the button, the program tries to make the text in the entrybox a float.  If it can't, it prints "Bad input".  Otherwise, it prints the float in the terminal.

Comment: Il try it but because im a beginner can you explain me what "try:" is and "except" is becaus ei have never seen it and what does you code:  myentry.delete(0, END) mean?

Comment: Cause i have entered it without that line and it worked perfectly !! Thanks

Comment: @ShahidIqbal -  All `myentry.delete(0, END)` does is clear the entrybox after you click the button.  It is basically saying "delete all text in the entrybox from character place 0 to the end".  And you are right--it is not _needed_.  I just put it there for convenience.

Comment: @ShahidIqbal - The try/except block is a very important concept in Python (as well as some other languages) that I _strongly_ suggest you look into.  It allows you to "try" code, but, if that code breaks (throws an error), you can run the code in the except part.  Here is a reference:  http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#try   try/except blocks allow you to have very efficient and easy to maintain code.